# How to add another className in react if I use CSS Modules?

Tags: reactjs

I have navbar with hamburger and I would like to add class `NavLinksActive` if I click on hamburger. Now, I have this: `<ul className={styles.NavLinks}>`.

How can I use:

```
this.state = {
            showMenu: false
```

to add new className if I click on burger?

Comment: Try to use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NPM [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package to conditionally add classes to components.

*Example*:

```js
var classNames = require('classnames');

var Button = React.createClass({
  // ...
  render () {
    var btnClass = classNames({
      btn: true, // this class will always be applied
      'btn-show-menu': this.state.showMenu // conditionally add css
    });
    return <button className={btnClass}>{this.props.label}</button>;
  }
});
```

*Note*: Without the package you could do something like this:

```js
var Button = React.createClass({
  // ...
  render () {
    var btnClass = 'btn';
    if (this.state.showMenu) btnClass += ' btn-show-menu';
    return <button className={btnClass}>{this.props.label}</button>;
  }
});
```

---

#### EDIT

Event handling example to clarify comments:
https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-bird-4jms3

Comment: How state will be change to (showMenu: true)? It should change if I click burger but how implement this in code?

Comment: You need to add an event handler take a look at the following doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html. You will have to add an onClick{} listener to the button.

Example: <button onClick={this.handleClick}>

Comment: Ok, but how to add new class if I use CSS Modules? Can you show me example on my data in question?

Comment: Using CSS modules:
<div className={classnames(styles.btn, {[styles.btn-show-menu]: this.state.showMenu})} />

Here is a help article on using multiple classnames using CSS modules in react:
https://zeph.co/multiple-classnames-css-modules-react

Comment: Thank you so much for help and articles! :) Good night my friend.